# Combine 2 simple SQL Server queries?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table :

```
id | Val
____________
1  | a
2  | s
3  | e
4  | f
5  | h
```

I have a query which accepts 2 params :

```
@id1 int
@id2 int
```

This query has 2 internal variables :

```
@val1 int
@val2 int
```

I need to set values into those variables : like -

```
select @val1=val from where id=@id1
select @val2=val from where id=@id2
```

I want to do it with **one** query.... I've tried:

```
select @val1=val , @val2=val  
from  table
where id=@id2 or  id=@id1
```

The problem is  :

`@val1` should set to `val` only when `id=@id1`

**and**

`@val2` should set to `val` only when `id=@id2`

(what about @val2 when id=@id1  ? what value will it get ?)

How can I write those 2 queries in 1 ?

Comment: Just leave it two selects, you're not gaining performance or readability by doing anything else.

Comment: @DanAndrews i disagree with you.

Comment: @RoyNamir Thank you for point that out?  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      @val1=CASE WHEN id=@id1 THEN Val ELSE @val1 END
    , @val2=CASE WHEN id=@id2 THEN Val ELSE @val2 END
FROM table
WHERE ID IN (@id1, @id2)
```

To test it out:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (ID INT, VAL CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (1,'a')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (2,'s')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3,'e')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (4,'f')
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (5,'h')

DECLARE @id1 INT=1
DECLARE @id2 INT=4

DECLARE @val1 CHAR(1)
DECLARE @val2 CHAR(1)

SELECT 
      @val1=CASE WHEN id=@id1 THEN Val ELSE @val1 END AS Val1
    , @val2=CASE WHEN id=@id2 THEN Val ELSE @val2 END AS Val2
FROM #tmp
WHERE ID IN (@id1, @id2)

SELECT @val1, @val2  --Returns a, f

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: Let me start out by saying that you've completely answered the question that the op asked.  I would like to add that if ID is the index, this query could perform worse than the two distinct queries.  It could go from an Index Seek to an Index Scan.

Comment: @DanAndrews, without the execution plan, a copy of his data, and other info to base things on, it's hard to say what solution is truly "best".

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a UNION which may or may not add to the readability of your query depending on who you ask.  I find it a bit more readable to the CASE statements or the temporary table solution.

```
select @val1=val from where id=@id1 
UNION
select @val2=val from where id=@id2
```

Comment: While you could consider it 2 queries it does bring the records back in a single result set which is really all that matters.  At least that is what I got out of your question was that you wanted to combine the results from each of the queries into a single result set.  I may have read too much into "single" query.  I do however think that of the other options listed it is the most readable.

Comment: For clarification, the temporary table was not part of the solution -- just was a way of allowing the person asking the question (or others) to quickly see that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you :

```
select @val1=val1 , @val2=val2 
FROM
(
select  
MAX(CASE WHEN id = @id1 THEN val END) AS val1,
MAX(CASE WHEN id = @id2 THEN val END) AS val2  
from  table 
where id=@id2 or  id=@id1 
)a
```

Comment: NOT WORKING.....`Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
`

Comment: @Royi Namir : Sorry, I didn't realize that `val` are nullable or underlying table may not have rows with `id =@id1` and `id =@id2`. However, it's actually working correctly. There are few workarounds that can be used with my approach. 1. Just ignore warning (the query returns right results despite the warning).  2. Disable ansi warnings (`SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`). 3. If `val` column cannot contain empty string, use `MAX(ISNULL(...,'')) 3. Use `pivot` equivalent of this query (unfortunately, it requires building dynamic query).

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
select (select @val1=val from where id=@id1) as val1,
(select @val2=val from where id=@id2) as val2
```